# Find shortest sequence of mathematical operations

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm mathematically trying to determine the shortest sequence of moves to reach a desired numerical result. I have two functions, both of which multiply a number by 2, and minus the value of the other number.

I've included my code so far, which has me manually calling the two functions to obtain the desired result; however, I would like help figuring out the logic to do this automatically with a loop.

```js
function findShortestSequence(number) {
    let left = 0;
    let right = 1;
    let moves = [];

    const moveLeft = () => {
        moves.push('L');
        left = 2 * left - right;
    }

    const moveRight = () => {
        moves.push('R');
        right = 2 * right - left;
    }

    moveLeft();
    moveLeft();
    moveRight();
    moveLeft();

    console.log(left, right, moves);
}

findShortestSequence(-11)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was just looking at -11, and considering 11 being 1011 in binary, which resembles your manual solution of LLRL, just backwards. Tests suggest that this may be the key for negative numbers: get their absolute value, and start shifting towards the right until it becomes zero. When you shift out an 1, move to the left, when you shift out a 0, move to the right. The last step will be a left-move, and the result goes into `left`.
Then I just checked what about positive numbers, simply swapping the moves (because leaving them in place would provide the negative result) and it appeared to generate one number above the goal. So I just subtracted one from the original and it started to work. Of course this time the last step is going to be a right-move, and result goes into `right`:

```js
function findShortestSequence(number) {
    let org = number;
    if(number<=0)number=-number; // work with absolute values when input is not positive
    else number--;               // work with one less, if input is positive
    let left = 0;
    let right = 1;
    let moves = [];

    const moveLeft = () => {
        moves.push('L');
        left = 2 * left - right;
    }

    const moveRight = () => {
        moves.push('R');
        right = 2 * right - left;
    }

    if(org<=0)
        while(number!=0){
          if(number&1)moveLeft();
          else moveRight();
          number>>=1;
        }
    else
        while(number!=0){
          if(number&1)moveRight();
          else moveLeft();
          number>>=1;
        }

    console.log(org, left, right, moves.join(''), (org==left)||(org==right));
}

for(var i=-20;i<=20;i++)
    findShortestSequence(i);
```

While I do not chase to provide a full explanation, I can provide some pieces which one may find useful:

- the "subtract 1 if positive" part feels like creating anti-two's complement number (in two's complement, in case of positive number you do not do anything, and in case of negative number you get its positive pair, invert its bits, and add 1 to the result)
- from a distance the "multiply by 2 and do a fix" is not that extreme:
  if one somehow ends up with `10001001` (137) and `1001` is the fixer, then multiply by 2 shifts everything to the left (`100010010`, 274), and if you want to keep that `0001001` part in its original place, subtracting the fixer "locally divides" that part back to its original place (`100010010`-`1001`=`100001001`), this is more or less what `moveRight` does to positive numbers
- updating the fixer is more convoluted, though some parts of it do resemble the previous idea: 2*`1001` becomes `10010`, and subtracting `10001001` fixes back `1001` on the lower places, and also introduces that `1` from the beginning at high places. The nasty part is that `10001001` is clearly larger than `10010`, so the result is a negative number, and in fact the fixer (`left` in case of a positive target number) has never been `1001`, because at its very first update ever, it becomes "2*`0`-something" (where "something" is a positive number, as `right` starts from 1). Indeed, looking at the example loop, `left` always seems to end up being non-positive, and `right` seems to be non-negative
- the anti-two's complement thing also uglifies the picture, it may be cleaner to think about negative target numbers first, as there the fixer (`right`) is non-negative, and `positive*2-negative` also stays positive:
  `...11110001001` (`left`) and `1001` (`right`), `...11110001001`*2 is `...111100010010`, and `...111100010010`-`1001`=`...111100001001`, first part of the mission is accomplished (keeping the `1001` pattern in place)
  and if the goal is to have `...1110010001001` later (after 2 `moveLeft`-s), then `moveRight` really does `1001`*2=`10010`, `10010`-`...11110001001`(-119)=`10001001`, which is exactly what is needed to extend the `1001` pattern into `10001001` for the 8 lowest places)
- about being "shortest": the fastest growing part is `moveRight`, if `left` remains 0 all the time, `right` jumps to the next power of two each step, so `ceil(log2(number))` steps are needed to reach or surpass the given number, which equals to the number of significant binary digits required represent the number, which equals the steps taken by the loop.

Comment: That is a great observation about using bitwise operators. One slight modification I've made is to get rid of the `if(org <= 0)` statement, and replace the `moveLeft()` and `moveRight()` with ternaries.

Comment: @AnonymousSB as I had some doubts about the "look, it is easy" explanation in the other answer, so added some thoughts about what is happening inside

Comment: Caleb Lucas' answer seems to me to fail with positive numbers. Am I misreading it? For example, any power of 2 would include an 'L', when clearly we only need R's. And testing just for 3 and -3 returns LL for both. How could that be?

Comment: @גלעדברקן That answer is simply wrong for positive numbers: returns the sequence producing the corresponding negative number, just mirrored. It fails to work starting from `1`, which should result in an empty sequence, as `right=1` already (same as for `0`, since `left=0` already)

Comment: @AnonymousSB this solution is far longer than the short one exactly because it does the calculation too. Unfortunately I did not think that adding `(org==left)||(org==right)` into the log-line was an absolute necessity.

Comment: Fair enough. With so much back and forth on the answers, it's easy to lose sight. Your answer is correct and does a very good job of explaining why. I suppose the ultimate question though is, do you accept the most elegant solution, or the first correct one. I think I've learned from this exchange that it's the latter.

Comment: @AnonymousSB The decision is yours alone, I was *asking* if there was any particular reason. This is the first time it is mentioned that you simply find the other code more elegant, and I can live with that. Feel free to revert, it is your choice alone.

Comment: @tevemadar i did undertand you code..  but under what ground knowledge you comeup wth this solution .. Under which domain of algorithms this specific question falls into.

Comment: @ArsalanAhmed It was a guess (nice wording: heuristic technique), I did not follow any kind of formal approach, really just looked at the bits in the binary representation of the number shown as example. Side note: https://cs.stackexchange.com/ may be the sister-site where questions about the theory of designing algorithms could be discussed.

Answer (score 4):

I think I came to the same conclusion as tevemadar. Here it is in code:

```js
function confirm(str, n){
  let l = 0;
  let r = 1;
  let i = 0;
  
  while(str[i]){
    if (str[i++] == 'L')
      l = 2*l - r;
    else
      r = 2*r - l;
  }
  
  if ([l, r].includes(n))
    return true;
    
  return false;
}

function f(n){
  if ([0, 1].includes(n))
    return '';
  else if (n > 1)
    return (n - 1)
      .toString(2)
      .split('')
      .map(x => x & 1 ? 'R' : 'L')
      .reverse()
      .join('');
  else
    return (-n)
      .toString(2)
      .split('')
      .map(x => x & 1 ? 'L' : 'R')
      .reverse()
      .join('');
}

for (let i=-11; i<=11; i++){
  fi = f(i);
  console.log(i + ': ' + fi + ', ' + confirm(fi, i));
}
```

Comment: While at least the faulty accepted answer is completely gone, I remain being puzzled why it is so important for OP to accept an answer which is a different one from mine...

Comment: I accepted this answer because the confirm function provided shows that it generates the correct moves, unless there is something I’m missing?

Answer (score 0):

You could take an iterative approach with a stack for the next state for checking the result.

This approach tests the smallest amount of changes first and then takes a growing count of possibilities.

```js
function findShortestSequence(number) {
    const
        moveLeft = (left, right, moves) => [left * 2 - right, right, [...moves, 'L']],
        moveRight = (left, right, moves) => [left, right * 2 - left, [...moves, 'R']],
        functions = [moveLeft, moveRight];

    var stack = [[0, 1, []]],
        left, right, moves;

    while ([left, right, moves] = stack.shift()) {
        if (left === number) return moves;
        functions.forEach(fn => stack.push(fn(left, right, moves)));
    }
}

console.log(findShortestSequence(-11));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How can you be sure that this terminates?

Comment: @Simone, it terminates, because of the finite value, and assuming the stack is deep enough.

Comment: @NinaScholz It doesn't terminate with positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also completely agree with myself, and find my hint useful (ok, that answer is gone).
If verification is not needed, generating the steps is this simple:

```js
function getSequence(n){
  if(n==0 || n==1)return "";
  var steps=n<0?["R","L"]:["L","R"];
  return (n<0?-n:n-1).toString(2)                        // get binary number
         .replace(/0/g,steps[0]).replace(/1/g,steps[1])  // replace digits with L/R
         .split('').reverse().join('');                  // reverse order
}

for(var i=-20;i<=20;i++)
  console.log(i,getSequence(i));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I really do appreciate your effort, and original observation about it being binary. This solution is much more succinct to @גלעדברקן's answer, and provides the same results. Quite smart to swap the steps ahead of time. Given that the max binary has a length of 31, I don't see any major issues with the time complexity; however, you could use cut down on one pass with this `replace` instead `.replace(/0|1/g, match => match === '0' ? steps[0] : steps[1])`